# Rounded rectange mousehover issue in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I am doing this extended tab menu but the rollover image is not working in IE6.. Is there any simple way to fix it ??

### HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="active"><a href="#"><span>Link 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Link 3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The sample file is posted here.... 
[Sample HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/uw4XY/1/)

Comment: FYI IE6 only supports :hover on `<a>` elements, there are numerous other IE6 bugs here too, which makes this hard to solve as-is. Check out some of the .htc :hover solutions for IE, might help (maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got some solutions already, but:

When you have the mouse over the span you also have it over the link, so try let the link handle the span. That would please IE6 too.

```
a:hover span { }
```

Comment: Thanks a Erik... dunno how I missed it.. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with this selector:

```
.menu span:hover
```

Unfortunately, while IE6 does support the `:hover` selector, it only supports it for `a` elements, so `a:hover` works, but `span:hover` doesn't.

This is one of many broken and missing features in IE6.

The good news is that there is a hack available which allows IE6 to support `:hover` for any element. It's called [Whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html).

Download the .htc file and add a reference to it in your stylesheet as described on the site, and it'll solve this particular IE6 issue.

To be honest, though, this isn't the only thing in IE6 that is going to hurt you. My recommendation, if at all possible, is to drop support for IE6. The number of people using IE6 is dropping rapidly, so it's becoming less and less relevant (last time I checked, it was getting less than 2% of the browser market share, and it's dropping by a quarter percent or more every month -- see http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-US-monthly-201003-201104). It's just not worth supporting any more.

But all that said, if this is the only issue you've got with IE6, then obviously you should use the whatever:hover hack -- it's virtually no effort, and it will solve this one problem, so it's clearly worth it.

Comment: +1, nicely written. Better than my attempt at [the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516799/css-xhtml-menu-working-in-all-browsers-ie6-help/5519476#5519476). Whatever:hover ftw!

Comment: Agree with the "drop IE" statement to some degree. Positioning or mouseovers aren't perfect === who cares. Site is unusable? Probably needs attention.

Answer (score -1):

I've run into the this before, but I can't remember if it works on IE 6.0. The short answer is that you need to define the rest of the related pseudo classes: http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_hover.asp

> Note: :hover MUST come after :link and :visited (if they are present) in the CSS definition, in order to be effective!

Try defining all 4 pseudo classes, even if they are blank.

```
a:link    {}
a:visited {}
a:hover   {color:red;}
a:active  {}
```

If all else fails, then just use jQuery's .hover() function:
http://api.jquery.com/hover